# Search text file in a web page and import the data in that text file into excel using vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have a web page and there is a text file in that web page. The text file name keeps changing every week.

How do I search for the text file in the web page and download the content into the excel sheet. Any pointers where to start? I know how to navigate to the webpage using a  given url.

The problem is I dont know the url of this text file( since it keeps changing every week), so how can I know this ?

http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/MannUsda/viewDocumentInfo.do?documentID=1048

here is the link for the web page. I need to download the txt file here (Crop Progress, 11.24.2014 [txt]) . Please help me out here.

Recorded Macro :

```css
Sub Macro4()
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;http://usda.mannlib.cornell.edu/usda/current/CropProg/CropProg-11-24-2014.txt" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .CommandType = 0
        .Name = "CropProg-11-24-2014"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll need to describe *exactly* how you'd manually do this.  Which link on that page do you need?

Comment: I want to download the file (Crop Progress, 11.24.2014 [txt]). Manually, I would just browse  this website, select the Crop Progress ,11.24.2014 txt file. Then it loads a new page. I copy the information from that page and use it. I tried recording a macro. I will post the code above.

Comment: You can get the html-code of page and parse it. For find links and get link by inner-html="txt" (<a href="..">txt</a>) and load href of this link. If cannot get html of page look at MSXHR Reguest by VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by opening the web page in an instance of Internet Explorer that you control from VBA (ShDocVw.InternetExplorer object from the Microsoft Internet Controls library). The InternetExplorer object has a member 'document' which contains the Document Object Model (DOM) holding all the HTML tags on the web page. Use the MSHTML library to work with the DOM.

You can search the DOM for an anchor element containing the text "txt". You can do this with an XPath query in document.SelectNodes(). If you don't want to use XPath, you can loop through the elements of document.all or use GetElementsByTagName().

Alternatively, you might find that the links on the page are the same every time (none added or removed) such that the link to the text file is always in the same place in the array returned by document.getelementsbytagname("a"). I.e. use something like document.GetElementsByTagName("a")(12) if it is always the 13th anchor tag on the page.

Once you have acquired a reference to the hyperlink to the text file, then the URL is in the href attribute of that anchor element.

Comment: hey thanks.. solved it .. searched for the A tags and then found the appropriate one by searching for element.innerText = "txt".